# If I have suggested an outdated/deprecated way of handling a problem, should I delete my answer or just edit it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, wrong-answers

My apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question - I saw a lot of questions like "should I delete my answer if it is wrong?", but none that address the scenario in which the solution is technically correct, but is recommended against by the documentation.

The question in question can be found here: [Search filter on Array Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377322/search-filter-on-array-angular-2/45378152?noredirect=1#comment77722965_45378152)

In this example, I offered up a solution, which was then pointed out by another user to be recommended against by the Angular documentation. I then edited my answer to reflect that it was not the preferred way of approaching the problem, and upvoted & suggested that the asker use the other user's answer, which is more correct.

The benefit to deleting the question is that the question is not clogged up with less correct answers.

However, the benefit to leaving the edited question is that more information is then given -- it would allow viewers of the question to not only learn the right way of answering the problem, but learn what not to do (and the reasons why not to do it) as well.

Comment: Definitely don't leave it with struck out text as currently.

Comment: If the current solution doesn't work on older versions of a library, then it might be worth it to still have the "outdated"/"deprecated" solution available in an answer. Not everyone is using the latest tools.

Answer (score 1):

More information isn't necessarily better.  If you think the answer isn't a good solution, and your answer is just telling people not to read it and to instead use another answer, then just delete the answer.  Why waste people's time reading enough of your answer to find out that they shouldn't use it, when they could instead just not see it at all and end up reading the *correct* answer right from the start?